# Could Not Deduce with Dependent Typing

Tags: haskell, dependent-type

I've been playing around with some cofree isomporphisms with dependent typing, and am getting an error message that just seems to be nonsense for me.

My dependently typed cofree

```
data Cofree (n :: Nat) f a where
  (:<<) :: a -> f (Cofree n f a) -> Cofree ('S n) f a
```

and isomorphism code

```
class Iso a b where
  toA :: b -> a
  toB :: a -> b
```

and my (very basic) instance (it's missing a lot of stuff but I want to just take care of the basics first)

```
instance Iso (Vec ('S n) a) (Cofree ('S n) Maybe a) where
  toA :: Cofree ('S n) Maybe a -> Vec ('S n) a
  toA (x :<< Nothing) = VCons x VNil
```

I figured that'd be the most basic thing possible, but it still type errors.

The error itself:

```
interactive>:224:127: error:
    * Could not deduce: n1 ~ 'Z
      from the context: 'S n ~ 'S n1
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
               :<< :: forall (f :: * -> *) a (n :: Nat).
                      a -> f (Cofree n f a) -> Cofree ('S n) f a,
             in an equation for `toA'
    at <interactive>:224:112-122
  `n1' is a rigid type variable bound by
    a pattern with constructor:
      :<< :: forall (f :: * -> *) a (n :: Nat).
             a -> f (Cofree n f a) -> Cofree ('S n) f a,
    in an equation for `toA'
    at <interactive>:224:112
  Expected type: Vec ('S n) a
    Actual type: Vec ('S 'Z) a
* In the expression: VCons x VNil
  In an equation for `toA': toA (x :<< Nothing) = VCons x VNil
  In the instance declaration for
    `Iso (Vec ('S n) a) (Cofree ('S n) Maybe a)'
```

which seems weird, since I don't get why it can't substitute 'Z in for n1 in the type equation, since that seems to solve it.

I tried doing the hole thing (so instead in my definition I had:

```
= _ $ VCons x VNil
```

which returned

```
 Found hole: _ :: Vec ('S 'Z) a -> Vec ('S n) a
```

which seems weird, since why couldn't I just supply id in there, it matches 'Z with n, and boom, solved?

By the way, the definitions for Nat and Vec I think are pretty normal so I didn't want to clutter up this post with more code than I needed, so I can provide them if it would be easier for somebody.

EDIT:
The Nat I used was

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat
```

and the Vec I used was

```
data Vec (n :: Nat) a where
  VNil :: Vec 'Z a
  VCons :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec ('S n) a
```

and no imports necessary, but GADTs, DataKinds, MultiParamTypeClasses, KindSignatures, and FlexibleInstances are necessary, and maybe PolyKinds? I don't quite remember.

Comment: BTW `data Iso a b = Iso { toA :: b -> a, toB :: a -> b }` will serve you much better than your class -- not in solving this problem, just in general.

Comment: `Vec ('S n) a` and `Cofree ('S n) Maybe a` are not isomorphic, so you'll have quite a bit of difficulty proving they are.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the right imports, language extensions, etc.

Comment: @luqui Why is that data structure more useful? Classes seem more intuitive to me, but my intuition could definitely be wrong on this (I'm a bit of a beginner).

Comment: @gallais Thank you for the link, that was very useful. I think I've added everything I needed.

Comment: @JackBrandt, just take it as a suggestion, it's worth experimenting with both ways to understand the ins and outs.

Comment: Ok, cool. I've tried both before, but never really compared the two. Was mostly wondering the differences.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get to choose the value of `n`. The caller of `toA` chooses that, and the definition of `toA` must be compatible with any choice.

Since there is no guarantee that the caller chooses `n ~ 'Z`, the type checker complains.

Indeed, `x :<< Nothing` can have type `Cofree ('S n) Maybe a`
but `VCons x VNil` only has type `Vec ('S 'Z) a` and not `Vec ('S n) a`.

Comment: Typo: `VCons x VNil` has type `Vec ('S 'Z) a`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you may pick `Maybe`'s `Nothing` constructor whenever you want but you can only use `Vec`'s `VNil` constructor when the index is `Z`. This mismatch makes the isomorphism impossible to implement.

You can however salvage the situation by:

- changing the definition of indexed `Cofree` so that its argument `f` is also indexed
- introducing a variant of `Maybe` where you may only use the `Nothing` constructor when the index is `Z`

In other words:

```
data ICofree (n :: Nat) f a where
  (:<<) :: a -> f n (ICofree n f a) -> ICofree ('S n) f a

data IMaybe (n :: Nat) a where
  INothing :: IMaybe 'Z a
  IJust    :: a -> IMaybe ('S n) a

instance Iso (Vec n a) (ICofree n IMaybe a) where
  toA (x :<< INothing) = VCons x VNil
  toA (x :<< IJust xs) = VCons x (toA xs)

  toB (VCons x VNil)       = x :<< INothing
  toB (VCons x xs@VCons{}) = x :<< IJust (toB xs)
```

And [a self-contained gist](https://gist.github.com/gallais/673b6e175032eef9f5fed1734b777912) with the right imports, language extensions and definitions.

Comment: So if I was planning on doing this with other functors, like Either and [], would I need to use dependently typed versions of them?

Comment: Probably, yeah.